# Coefficient in magnetic susceptibility calculation

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, solid-state-physics

There is a relation in my laboratory course manual that says the following:
$L = L_0(1+\alpha \chi)$, where $\chi$ is magnetic susceptibility of the sample and $\alpha$ is a constant that depends on geometrical factors, such as the fraction of the coil occupied by the sample (filling factor) and the demagnetization coefficient.

How can I find out how to calculate $\alpha$ explicitly? I have tried to find this relation elsewhere, but I cannot, and I do not know what this coefficient is known as.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, this relation is likely to be an empirical law, an first-order linear approximation with respect to $\chi$. If it is the case, then a experiment and linear regression would figure out the $\alpha$ coefficient.

However, if you give us more insights on what $L$ (maybe induction ?) is and what is your experiment setup then there should be a theoretical deduction of $\alpha$.

Comment: Hi! So, a sample is placed in a coil, which is part of an LC oscillator. The effect of the sample is to change the inductance of the coil. The change in inductance produces a corresponding change in frequency of the LC oscillator, which is measured by a computer. Since I can measure the frequency, I can get the values for inductances. I believe it should be possible to calculate this alpha directly, but I am unsure.

Comment: actually, i cannot find the inductance values without knowing $\alpha$ i have just realized.

Comment: I found most equation for inductance is propotional to $\mu = 1 + \chi$. So it is likely that $\alpha$ equals 1.